# Point Texture/Image in the direction of the cursor in raylib c++

Tags: c++, raylib

I'm am programing a simple game and I need a character/sprite to face the cursor at all times, is this possible with raylib and c++? Do I need any other tools?

I tried treating the image as a Vector2d

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `atan2` function in cmath returns an angle pointing towards the x and y position in radians, here's an example using `atan2`:

```
float x = GetMouseX() - position.x,
y = GetMouseY() - position.y;
float rotation = atan2(x, y) * -57.29578f; // Multiplies the angle by -57.295 to convert to degrees

DrawTexturePro(Image, Rectangle{0, 0, (float)Image.width, (float)Image.height},
                       { position.x, position.y, ImgWidth, ImgHeight },
                       { ImgHeight/2, ImgWidth/2 }, rotation+180, RAYWHITE);
```